# Missing mdadm raid5 array reassembles as raid0 after powerout

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, raid5

I had RAID5 array of three disks with no spares. There was a power out, and on reboot, the array failed to come back up. In fact, the /dev/md127 device disappeared entirely, and was replaced by an incorrect /dev/md0. It was the only array on the machine. I've tried to reassemble it from the three component devices, but the assembly keeps creating a raid0 array instead of a raid5.

The details of the three disks are

```
root@bragi ~ # mdadm -E /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 002fa352:9968adbd:b0efdfea:c60ce290
           Name : bragi:0  (local to host bragi)
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 30 00:10:47 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 2930269954 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
     Array Size : 2930269184 (2794.52 GiB 3000.60 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930269184 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=770 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : a8a1b48a:ec28a09c:7aec4559:b839365e

    Update Time : Sat Oct 11 09:20:36 2014
       Checksum : 7b1ad793 - correct
         Events : 15084

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@bragi ~ # mdadm -E /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 002fa352:9968adbd:b0efdfea:c60ce290
           Name : bragi:0  (local to host bragi)
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 30 00:10:47 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 2930269954 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
     Array Size : 2930269184 (2794.52 GiB 3000.60 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930269184 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=770 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 36c08006:d5442799:b028db7c:4d4d33c5

    Update Time : Wed Oct 15 08:09:37 2014
       Checksum : 7e05979e - correct
         Events : 15196

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : .A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@bragi ~ # mdadm -E /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x8
     Array UUID : 002fa352:9968adbd:b0efdfea:c60ce290
           Name : bragi:0  (local to host bragi)
  Creation Time : Sun Oct 30 00:10:47 2011
     Raid Level : raid5
   Raid Devices : 3

 Avail Dev Size : 2930275057 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
     Array Size : 2930269184 (2794.52 GiB 3000.60 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 2930269184 (1397.26 GiB 1500.30 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1960 sectors, after=5873 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b048994d:ffbbd710:8eb365d2:b0868ef0

    Update Time : Wed Oct 15 08:09:37 2014
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors - bad blocks present.
       Checksum : bdbc6fc4 - correct
         Events : 15196

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : .A. ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

I stopped the old array, then reassembled as follows (blank lines inserted for clarity)

```
root@bragi ~ # mdadm -S /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0

root@bragi ~ # mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 1 drive and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.

root@bragi ~ # cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : inactive sdd1[1](S) sde1[3](S) sdc1[2](S)
      4395407482 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
root@bragi ~ # mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
     Raid Level : raid0
  Total Devices : 3
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

          State : inactive

           Name : bragi:0  (local to host bragi)
           UUID : 002fa352:9968adbd:b0efdfea:c60ce290
         Events : 15084

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1

root@bragi ~ # mdadm -Q /dev/md0
/dev/md0: is an md device which is not active
```

Why is this assembling as a raid0 device and not a raid5 device, as the superblocks of the components indicate it should? Is it because /dev/sde1 is marked as spare?

**EDIT:** I tried the following (according to @wurtel's suggestion), with the following results

```
# mdadm --create -o --assume-clean --level=5 --layout=ls --chunk=512 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md0 missing /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 appears to contain an ext2fs file system
       size=1465135936K  mtime=Sun Oct 23 13:06:11 2011
mdadm: /dev/sdd1 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid5 devices=3 ctime=Sun Oct 30 00:10:47 2011
mdadm: /dev/sde1 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid5 devices=3 ctime=Sun Oct 30 00:10:47 2011
mdadm: partition table exists on /dev/sde1 but will be lost or
       meaningless after creating array
Continue creating array? no
mdadm: create aborted.
#
```

So it looks like /dev/sde1 is causing the problem again. I suspect this is because it has been marked as spare. Is there anyway I can force change its role back to active? In this case I suspect assembling the array might even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a rather scrambled-looking system there.  The key elements from your `mdadm --examine` output:

```
/dev/sdc1:
    Update Time : Sat Oct 11 09:20:36 2014
         Events : 15084

   Device Role : Active device 2

/dev/sdd1:
    Update Time : Wed Oct 15 08:09:37 2014
         Events : 15196

   Device Role : Active device 1

/dev/sde1:
    Update Time : Wed Oct 15 08:09:37 2014
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors - bad blocks present.
         Events : 15196

   Device Role : spare
```

You were unable to re-assemble the array because `/dev/sdc1` has a lower event count than the other two (the data on it is out of date), while `/dev/sde1` is marked as being a spare (the data on it bears no relation to the state of the array).  This gives you only one data-containing drive, while a three-disk RAID 5 needs a minimum of two to start running.  I've got no idea how you got here, since this doesn't look like a typical two-drive failure.

Since the event counts for `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdd1` don't differ by much, you may be able to recover most or all of the data by forcing `mdadm` to re-assemble the array from those two volumes.  You'll probably want to follow the procedure from [the Linux RAID Wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID), but if you don't mind the possibility of losing everything, the key step is `mdadm --assemble --force --run /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1`, followed by a `fsck` -- this will either work, or destroy the array entirely, and the point of the extended procedure is to figure out which it will be without actually harming the data.

Alternatively, since `/dev/sdd1` and `/dev/sde1` have identical event counts, you *may* be able to recover everything by changing the metadata on `/dev/sde` to mark it as having a device role of "Active device 0", but this is the sort of thing that requires expert knowledge and direct hex-editing of the disk contents.

Comment: How I got here is a long story involving a field mouse inside the house, a mad sausage dog, and a rats nest of cables... And to add insult to injury, a power failure near the end of the rebuild. sde got knocked out by the cable/dog incident, not sure why it got marked as spare when I plugged it back in through,

Comment: FYI: I followed the wiki instructions and was able to force assemble excluding sde, which worked with relatively little corruption. What I lost I had backed up

Comment: That makes sense.  When `/dev/sde` got disconnected, it would have fallen out of sync with the rest of the array, and needed rebuilding, and it'll be marked as a spare until the rebuild is complete.  The difference in event counts between `/dev/sdc1` and `/dev/sdd1` could be due to caching: `/dev/sdd1`'s cache got flushed before the power failed, while `/dev/sdc1`'s didn't.  If you're in a situation where intermittent failures of hard drives are a possibility, consider adding an internal write-intent bitmap to the array: it'll slow down normal operations a little, but speed up rebuilds a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If a device is missing from an mdadm RAID5, I "create" the RAID device again with the old settings and `missing` as the missing device, e.g. in your situation it should be:

```
mdadm --create --level=5 --layout=ls --chunk=512 --raid-devices=3 /dev/md0 missing /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdc1
```

Note: I'm assuming the "Device role" is 0-based, I'm used to a somewhat older mdadm -E output format. I.e. that the first device is missing. If it's 1-based, then apparently the third device is missing so then put `missing` at the end instead of the beginning of the device list.

Comment: Do I need to use --assume-clean? won't creating the array again wipe the data?

Comment: It could be helpful and I recommend you do use it, although I've done this without that option. The point is that because of the missing device it can't really wipe anything, at least that;s how it used to work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've edited the question with the results.